# relationship between Eigen Value and continuity of geometry

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, continuity, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the paper "Sederberg, T. W., Zheng, J., Bakenov, A., & Nasri, A. (2003). T-splines and T-NURCCs. ACM transactions on graphics (TOG), 22(3), 477-484."
eigenvalue is used to prove the continuity of geometry. It's my first time to find someone gives a relationship between those.
I was wondering why we can get continuity of geometry based on eigenvalue. The following picture is the detail.

[image]

Comment: I can't guess which kind of **matrix** has given these eigenvalues : couldn't you give a larger excerpt from this article in order for us to be able to help you...

Comment: @JeanMarie I update with larger excerpt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smoothness (order of continuity) of a subdivision surface is related to the eigenvalues of the subdivision matrix. This is a well-known approach to smoothness analysis. If you search for "subdivision surface" and "eigenvalue", you'll find lots of references on the subject.

A good place to start might be [this book by Peters and Rief](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540764054).

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very helpful